# Is it harmful to set the same cursor for a FrameworkElement many times per second in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouse-cursor

We are using a external library component in our WPF application.

Depending on where the mouse hovers, the cursor needs to change.

For that, the component fires events that we need to handle in "OnSetCursor" and "OnResetCursor" handlers. The events are fired nearly each time the mouse moves over the component, so hundreds of times in seconds.

In examples from the libraries, they are doing something like this :

```
private void OnResetCursor(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (myComponent.Cursor != System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow)
        myComponent.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

`myComponent` inherits from `FrameworkElement`, that's where `Cursor` is defined.

A quick look on the decompiled WPF source shows it's just an automatic property `Cursor { get; set; }`

Is there any drawback to remove the check?

```
private void OnResetCursor(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    myComponent.Cursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Code review comment suggest me that the code should not contain this check if it doesn't cause unwanted behavior.

A quick test on my machines shows no weird flickering, and no measurable performance impact. But maybe there are cases that I overlooked or can't test locally.

I haven't found any remarks about that in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It doesn't look like automatic property: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs,3879. DP should ignore repeated assignments of the same value

Comment: IMO the code review comment makes no sense. You want to check whether a property already has a certain value before assigning that value. That's totally reasonable.

Comment: @ASh thank you very much for this link, didn't know the non-core source was available.

Comment: @Pac0, yes, they released it some years ago. Given amount of operations in SetValue() method, I would say, your check with if *is actually faster* than repeated assignment :)

Comment: @ASh Well, there is a lot of checks performed in the `GetValue()` as well, I don't feel confident estimating the cost of this.

Comment: This third party library created with WPF? If so you can try to create custom styles for UI elements with your own custom Cursors.

Comment: @Shakra the actual parts that triggers the cursor change are not WPF. Basically, they are elements in an image. The Image container/viewer is WPF, but all the details inside are not, unfortunately, they are handled internally by the library. The only interface we have to change the cursor are those events mentioned in the question.